# How to prevent UIWebView from scrolling past its boundaries?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a view with a `UIWebView` as a sub-view, along with some other (fixed) subviews.  I want the `UIWebView` to be scrollable in every direction, but I don't want the user to be able to drag the contents past their natural boundaries, as illustrated here:

[image]

In this image, I'm dragging the webview's contents down and to the right, and as you can see the contents go past their top and left boundaries.  I want the contents to just stop right at the edges when this happens, so that no gray area is exposed underneath.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
  if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
    ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```

Comment: Sorry, already tried this one, too.  It removes the bouncing effect (and makes the scrolling weirdly "sticky") but doesn't prevent dragging the contents past their boundaries.

Comment: Anybody can confirm this code has been approved by apple ? I've been warned on this kind of coding.

Comment: `[[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]` can be written as `[subview isKindOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]`